# Clarification @ConcurrentModificationException in HashMap

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I am expecting a `ConcurrentModificationException` in the follow code, but it's working fine.

```
HashMap<Integer, String>table1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    table1.put(1, "Sam");
    table1.put(2, "Jon");
    table1.put(3, "Doe");

    Iterator itr1 = table1.entrySet().iterator();

    table1.put(3, "DONN");
    while(itr1.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println("---Value--" + itr1.next());
    }
```

As per the JavaDoc for `HashMap`:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.

So since I am modifying the `HashMap` after getting the `Iterator` I should be getting the `ConcurrentModificationException`. Why is it not throwing?

Comment: The documentation also states: "Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting an entry for an *existing* key is not considered a *structural modification* in the current implementation of `HashMap`and will never trigger a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Try putting with a new key, e.g. `table1.put(4, "UPS");` to get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the `HashMap` not the entrySet that you are obtaining on it, and here you are obtaining the `iterator` over the `entrySet`:

As per `entrySet` method javaDoc:

> If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined.

So you are not getting `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Here is the full explaination of entrySet:

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the iterator) the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

Comment: “undefined” does not preclude throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException` and in the current implementation it *does* throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` but only if keys are added or removed.

Comment: Yup, got it, since he is using the same key, the `HashMap` is not getting modified.

Answer (score 2):

try `table1.put(4, "DONN")` and iterator will fail with ConcurrentModificationException. `table1.put(3, "DONN")` does not change map structure but just replaces value for key=3 since it's already there