# Any Idea why I am not getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException while removing key from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrentmodification

What i want to achieve is if key is key to be removed.Change the key to current time but its value should be same.

My code snippet is:

```
public class hello
{
    private static HashMap<String,String> fileMap;
    private static final String KEY_REMOVED = "d";
    static {
        fileMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        fileMap.put("a", "hello");
        fileMap.put(KEY_REMOVED, "bye");
        fileMap.put("c", "hi");
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        upload();
}

    private static void upload() throws  ConcurrentModificationException {

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Uploading key " + entry.getKey());

            String fileName = entry.getKey();

            if (fileName.equals(KEY_REMOVED)) {
                fileName = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
                String temp2 = fileMap.remove(VIDEO_MP4_ASSET);
                System.out.println("hashmap after removing key is " + fileMap);
                System.out.println("adding  key to hashmap " + fileName);
                fileMap.put(fileName, temp2);

            } else {

                System.out.println("continue");
            }
            System.out.println("hashmap is " + fileMap);
        }
    }
```

Ideally while removing key we should get ConcurrentModificationException.I am worried that I am not getting it right now.But my code might break later.Is it?

Comment: If you're looping an array, you can't perform operations on the array at the same time. You should make another array that stores a list of everything you want to remove and then remove them after you're done looping.

Comment: @R10t-- You cannot remove an element from array by any means whatsoever. And generally you can iterate through collections and remove items as long as you explicitly use iterator.

Comment: Why is there a `System.out.println("Hello World");` and a lot of other seemingly random things included?

Comment: removed System.out.println("Hello World");

Answer (score 2):

This can be a bit confusing since the Javadoc first states that

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view
>   methods" (`values()`, `keySet()`, `entrySet()`) are fail-fast: if the
>   map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is
>   created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method,
>   the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed

But it also states at [HashMap.entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet--)

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa. **If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is
>   in progress** (except through the iterator's own remove operation, or
>   through the setValue operation on a map entry returned by the
>   iterator) **the results of the iteration are undefined**.

now **undefined** *does* include throwing a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but there are [many cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22223673/clarification-concurrentmodificationexception-in-hashmap/22223899) where it's not thrown because as seen in the beginning, the fail-fast behaviour **cannot be guaranteed**.

So if you're iterating on `keySet()`, `values()` or `entrySet()` and you're modifying the `Map` structurally, i.e. `remove()` or `put` with a new key (not replacing the value of an existing key), you may get: a `ConcurrentModificationException` or weird things happening with the iteration, such as skipping elements or encountering an element twice.

Comment: This.  The code isn't iterating over the `HashMap`, but rather a `Set` of `Map.Entry`.

Comment: So what is the right way to to achieve both remove() and put() in same iteration? or change key but keep same value? or rename key in hashmap while iterating?

Comment: @darshpreetnarula there's no *proper* way, you usually want to avoid that sort of design completely. But as a workaround you can have two additional helper maps `toAdd` and `toRemove` where you store your changes, and then after iterating you make the modifications to the map. Or you could tell what you're [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) trying to do, so a better design can be proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are not required to detect any concurrent modification and throw an exception. Indeed it is rather difficult to guarantee a concurrent modification exception on any arbitrary concurrent modification. You should never rely on this exception being thrown.

In your example, if you want to guarantee no concurrent modification takes place, you need to create a temporary copy of your entryset for the purpose of iteration. The best way to do this would be to change the line

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : fileMap.entrySet()) {
```

to

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : new ArrayList<>(fileMap.entrySet())) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the right way to rename key in hashmap while iterating ?

Storing value in temp variable,Removing key and put new entry with new key and temp

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> iter = fileMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) { 

Map.Entry<String, String> entry = iter.next(); 
fileName = entry.getKey(); 

if (fileName.equals(KEY_REMOVED)) {
fileName = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime(); 
String temp = entry.getValue(); 
iter.remove(); 
System.out.println("hashmap after removing key is " + fileMap); 
fileMap.put(fileName, temp); 
System.out.println("Updated hashmap after addng key is " + fileMap); 
} 
else
{
 System.out.println("continue");
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ConcurrentModificationException is not intended to be a safe mean to know if something changes your collection as Documentation about HashMap says:
"Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs"

if you want to be sure nobody changes your collection you can use a synchronized version of HashMap :

Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedMap()` does not prevent a `ConcurrentModificationException`. The "concurrent" word has nothing to do with multithreading in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @kayaman I was confused for the use of the word concurrent in the documentation "If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally."